# Android Studio 135.1641136: does not launch app

Tags: java, windows-7, android-studio, ide

I checked many solutions for this problem but none works for me.

- studio64.exe not work. Running as administrator not work.
- studio.exe tell me: "We have detected that you are running a 64-bit version of the Windows bla  bla bla ..."

PLEASE HELP ME !!!

- Where more places I must check and change?
- Where I can find a log from launching?
- What other information need you from me?
- What other executable combination I must try (ie.: studio64.exe --help)

Thanks a lot.

---

### MY WINDOWS

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Service Pack 1
- System type: 64-bit Operating System

### MY PATH

```
    PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\GTK\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\cygwin\bin;C:\Heroku\bin;C:\Heroku\git\cmd;C:\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin;C:\java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin
```

### MY JAVA HOME

JAVA_HOME = C:\java\jdk1.8.0_25

### MY JAVA

```
    C:\java\android-studio\bin>java -version
    java version "1.8.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

    C:\java\android-studio\bin>javac -version
    javac 1.8.0_25

    C:\java\android-studio\bin>
    C:\java\android-studio\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
    C:\java\jdk1.8.0_25

    C:\java\android-studio\bin>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version
    java version "1.8.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

    C:\java\android-studio\bin>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac -version
    javac 1.8.0_25
```

```
ANDROID STUDIO
--------------
Build: AI-135.1641136
<pre>
C:\java\android-studio\bin>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7A92-303B

 Directory of C:\java\android-studio\bin

01/10/2015  10:58 AM    <DIR>          .
01/10/2015  10:58 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/11/2014  09:40 PM               136 appletviewer.policy
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            28,672 breakgen.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            40,448 breakgen64.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            32,768 focuskiller.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            50,688 focuskiller64.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            71,208 fsnotifier.exe
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            71,004 idea.ico
12/11/2014  09:40 PM             6,970 idea.properties
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            36,352 IdeaWin32.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            42,496 IdeaWin64.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            54,784 jumplistbridge.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            61,952 jumplistbridge64.dll
12/11/2014  09:40 PM             2,275 log.xml
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            52,736 restarter.exe
12/11/2014  09:40 PM           106,088 runnerw.exe
12/11/2014  02:39 PM           546,120 studio.exe
12/11/2014  09:40 PM               412 studio.exe.vmoptions
12/11/2014  02:39 PM           563,528 studio64.exe
12/11/2014  09:40 PM               430 studio64.exe.vmoptions
12/11/2014  09:40 PM            63,048 vistalauncher.exe
              20 File(s)      1,832,115 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  266,038,730,752 bytes free
```

**WARNING:** No *.bat files here. Is normal that ???

### SYSTEMINFO

```
        C:\Users\Diego>systeminfo

        Host Name:                 LAPTOPDCUEVA
        OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
        OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
        OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
        OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
        OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
        Registered Owner:          Diego
        Registered Organization:   Hewlett-Packard
        Product ID:                00359-OEM-8992687-00010
        Original Install Date:     8/7/2011, 9:50:38 PM
        System Boot Time:          1/12/2015, 8:38:00 AM
        System Manufacturer:       Hewlett-Packard
        System Model:              HP Pavilion dv4 Notebook PC
        System Type:               x64-based PC
        Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                                   [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~1578 Mhz
        BIOS Version:              Insyde F.0E, 9/2/2010
        Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
        System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
        Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
        System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
        Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
        Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco
        Total Physical Memory:     3,895 MB
        Available Physical Memory: 1,772 MB
        Virtual Memory: Max Size:  7,788 MB
        Virtual Memory: Available: 5,150 MB
        Virtual Memory: In Use:    2,638 MB
        Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
        Domain:                    CASA
        Logon Server:              \\LAPTOPDCUEVA
```

```
<hr>
<pre>

    Network Card(s):           4 NIC(s) Installed.
                               [01]: Broadcom 43225 802.11b/g/n
                                     Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection
                                     DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                     DHCP Server:     192.168.1.1
                                     IP address(es)
                                     [01]: 192.168.1.110
                                     [02]: fe80::69b1:e294:eaf2:201
                               [02]: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
                                     Connection Name: Local Area Connection
                                     Status:          Media disconnected
                               [03]: Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
                                     Connection Name: Wireless Network Connection 2
                                     Status:          Media disconnected
                               [04]: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
                                     Connection Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network
                                     DHCP Enabled:    No
                                     IP address(es)
                                     [01]: 169.254.124.165
                                     [02]: fe80::d982:3e93:2a80:7ca5
```

### JAVA WORKING TEST

This is a Swing app running under jdk

```
    C:\Users\Diego\Documents\GoogleDrive\workspace\Symja>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath lib;bin Symja
    Config.SHOW_STACKTRACE == true
            isFlatAST
            isOrderlessAST
            isTimes
        :[2]
       isFlatAST isOrderlessAST isTimes
          #Rational(1,2) : isPositive isNumericFunction isAtom isFraction isNumber isRational isRealFunction isSignedNumber
           :[2]
          isPower
             #x : isAtom isVariable isSymbol
             #2 : isNumIntValue isPositive isEven isNumericFunction isAtom isInteger isNumber isRational isRealFunction isSignedNumber
          
       
    --------------------

    C:\Users\Diego\Documents\GoogleDrive\workspace\Symja>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version
    java version "1.8.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

    C:\Users\Diego\Documents\GoogleDrive\workspace\Symja>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a 64-bit windows? And can you run java programs normally ?

Comment: Have a look at this course: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1395568821/e-1395668582/m-1395668583 It helped me build and deploy an app.

Comment: Hi: Thanks for check my problem.
I added more info:
  - SystemInfo
  - JDK 1.8 running test.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workarrounf for this problem.
Craeate a file named studio.bat and put in the content below.
Put this file in the same STUDIO path.

Be aware, you must setup the paths at the beginning of studio.bat for your local Java and Studio installations
Put a shortcut for studio.bat in pc desktop and enjoy it.


Grettings

```
    @echo off
    rem ------------------------------
    rem Workarround for studio64.exe
    rem ------------------------------

    rem Setup here your home paths
    set   JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk1.8.0_25
    set STUDIO_HOME=C:\java\android-studio


    set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
    set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx256m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioBeta -Djb.vmOptionsFile=%STUDIO_HOME%\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions  -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioBeta -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
    set CLASSPATH=%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\bootstrap.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\extensions.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\util.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\jdom.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\log4j.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\trove4j.jar;%STUDIO_HOME%\lib\jna.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

    %JAVA_EXE% %JAVA_OPTS% -cp %CLASSPATH% com.intellij.idea.Main
```